# How to rebind a telerik MVC grid having dynamic name

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

I am using Telerik MVC Grid.

I want to rebind a grid which has a dynamic name like:

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid<ViewModel>()
        .Name("Grid" + Model.PrimaryKey)
        .DataKeys(key => key.Add("PrimaryKey").RouteKey("PrimaryKey"))
        .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(m => m.PrimaryKey).Title("Key1").Width(110);              
           }
        .Render();
    %>
```

In general case we rebind grid in js like:

```
var grid = $("Grid").data("tGrid");
                 if (grid != null) {
                     grid.rebind();
                 }
```

In this case, how can I rebind the grid?

Answer (score -1):

Use server-side code to write the variable value into your client-side code. Something like (using Razor syntax):

```
var grid = $("#Grid@(Model.PrimaryKey)").data("tGrid");
if (grid != null) {
  grid.rebind();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the resplonse, I tried this but it is displaying grid as undefined.

Comment: My example was using Razor syntax. I don't remember what the syntax is for the other rendering engine. Maybe `<%= Model.PrimaryKey %>`?